# How to do Laurent Series Expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) =  \frac{3}{(z-1)(z-7)}$

in the domain $\{z: 1<|z|<7\}$

I remember the first step is to put $f(z)$ in partial fractions.This gives me

$ \frac{3}{8(x-7)}$ $- \frac{3}{8(x+1)}$

What the next step ?

I'm struggling to get to the result, thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the first part of the partial fraction and ignoring the coefficient,

$\dfrac{1}{z-7} = -\dfrac{1}{7}(\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{z}{7}}) = -\dfrac{1}{7}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{7})^n$

Where we get the sum by noticing that we have the limit of a geometric series, and we have the formula $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$,
 so of course, we could just put the series there (in this case, $a=1$, $r=\frac{z}{7}$). It is convergent in the annulus as $|\frac{z}{7}|<1$.

The other part is analagous, and sticking it all together will yield the Laurent series.

Comment: thanks, how does 

$\ -\dfrac{1}{7}(\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{z}{7}}) = -\dfrac{1}{7}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{z}{7})^n$ ?

and how do I know which is the first part , because sometimes the first bracket may have been -3/8(x+1)

Comment: Clarified that step in the answer. It doesn't matter which is the first part in your partial fractions, I was just saying what I was doing.